# Is there a way to disable MUI date picker showing today's date on page load

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use mui datepicker and it is showing today's date on page render,but actually no date is selected.
I tried giving no defaultValue prop and also tried these :-

```
defaultValue={null}
defaultValue=""
```

still it is showing today's date

Comment: well how exactly do you use it? 
https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-material-demo-forked-6mp03?file=/demo.js
If I just change the value to null, it does not show a default value.
you probably set it somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Leviathan when I put `value={value}` on Page render the field is empty(thats what needed) but even after I select a date,that date is not displaying in the field

Comment: well the examples are clearly working, so you should either show your code or - preferable - build a codesandbox / codepen version like the one I linked in my comment, so people can see and fiddle around with what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `null` to the `value` prop instead of passing it to the `defaultValue` prop

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Date"
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

for more information checkout [Date Picker](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/)

Comment: This code `onChange={(newValue) => {setValue(newValue);}}` can be `onChange={setValue}` to be more optimized.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli when I put `value={value}` on Page render the field is empty(thats what needed) but even after I select a date,that date is not displaying in the field

Comment: @AlanShajanMattathil you have to pass a state variable to the `value` prop with an initial value of `null`. then you have to pass a function to the `onChange` prop which will receive the value that the user input as the first argument which you have to use to update the state variable you passed to the `value` prop. see the example in the answer.

Comment: @AmjedOmar I did exactly that,but its not working

Comment: @AlanShajanMattathil the example is working fine check it out on https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-material-ui-7jnjo?file=/src/App.js, so ensure that you implement the `value` and the `onChange` props correctly like the example in the answer, otherwise show the code you write so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how is your code . But write the code in this way i got the value but unfortunately i didn't set the default value but on Update case with this code i can set the date that received from backend ..

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DatePicker
                    maxDate={dayjs(new Date())}
                    onChange={(value) => changeDate(value, values, 'checkIn')}
                    value={dayjs(values?.checkIn)}
                    slotProps={{
                      textField: {
                        size: 'small',
                        fullWidth: true,
                        error: touched?.employee && Boolean(errors?.employee) ? true : false,
                      },
                    }}`enter code here`
                    name="checkIn"
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
```